# For loop in Velocity

Tags: java, velocity

I want to use for loop in a Velocity view. I want to take a counter variable in velocity view and loop till it equals. e.g

```
counter = 3
for(i=0; i< counter; i++){

...

}
```

Comment: It is the [first result](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html#aforeach_-_Loops_through_a_list_of_objects) on google for "velocity for loop"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `foreach` for this, by defining a range and iterating over it.

```
#set($start = 0)
#set($end = 3)
#foreach($i in [$start..$end])
   ...
#end
```

Comment: Excellent, and you can do #foreach($i in [0..10]) if you just want a hardcoded loop.

Comment: Note this loops 4 times with `$i` being [0, 1, 2, 3], unlike the for loop in the question `for(i=0; i< counter; i++)` which loops 3 times with `i` being [0, 1, 2].

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer works fine, but do note it loops 4 times total because the start and end are inclusive in a Velocity `#foreach` loop. Another way to do it if you want a zero-indexed loop and have an exclusive end value, is to use the builtin `$foreach.index`. If you want to loop `$n` times:

```
#foreach($unused in [1..$n])
    zero indexed: $foreach.index
#end
```

here, `$unused` is unused, and we instead use `$foreach.index` for our index, which starts at 0.

In the question's case, `$n` is 3.

We start the range at 1 as it's inclusive, and so it will loop with `$unused` being [1, 2, 3], whereas `$foreach.index` will be [0, 1, 2].

See [the user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#foreach-loop) for more.

Comment: Nice catch! It's been a long time since I used velocity :)